# How to login or refresh the JWT without re-authorizing the application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, auth0

I think I've misunderstood something relatively basic, but I can't figure out exactly what.

I'm trying to put [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authentication ([OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Connect_(OIDC))) on a static website.  Frustratingly, in context I cannot use any of the regular SDKs for this and I need to implement this from scratch by forming the right HTTP requests and redirect URLs.  I need to embed my code in the CDN and none of the libraries I've at are compatible.

What I'm stuck on: **login requests always result in the user being forced to to re-authorize my app on the identity provider every time**. Every login, they are asked permission to shared their identity with my web server.  This is true both when using either [Auth0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okta,_Inc.#History) or [Google Workspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Workspace) as the identity provider.

I do not want a token that I can continually refresh while the user is offline.  I simply want to be able to re-confirm that the person sitting at the screen is still the same user the web server saw previously... or rather delegate that responsibility to the identity provider.  So when the current [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) expires, I want to bounce the user back to the identity provider for a new one without the identity provider asking if my app is allowed access to their identity.

---

## What I'm doing right now

All of the documentation I read discusses redirecting the client to the `authorization_endpoint` listed in the [OpenID Connect Discovery Document](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect).  This endpoint always seems to ask the user to confirm that my web app is allowed access.

I don't see documentation of what I'm supposed to do when a user has already granted access and is simply trying to login.

As an example, I redirect a user to the Auth0 authorization endpoint with the following parameters:

- `response_type`=`id_token`
- `response_mode`=`form_post`
- `scope`=`email profile openid`
- `redirect_uri`=`http://localhost:8080/oauth_endpoint` *also tried with https*
- `nonce`=`3047586235078631450876135`
- `state`=`3405723460897624309836713gdfzbzj`

This results in a JWT that I can interrogate for the user's details (great!). But what am I supposed to do when this expires (in an hour)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Microsoft's documentation on this looks better than most I've seen.  You may want to look over Microsoft's documentation even if you are working with Google or Auth0, as it's descriptions also plainly discuss what happens when sessions expire as part of discussing the flow.*

The missing detail was that I needed to set `prompt`=`none` ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)) when directing authorisation endpoint.  This asks the identity provider to authorise a session using the browser's existing single sign-on session.

This might result in a `login_required` error.  In that case the app can just retry authorising, but this time with `prompt`=`login`.

Comment: Interesting! That option wasn't even on my radar. Thanks for sharing. So I'm curious, do you still have to use the redirect workflow or can you make an XHR call in Javascript and get back the code in the response? Seems like the latter would be quite useful but the former could be a pain if you have to account for saving/restoring your app state.

Comment: @EmperorEto I saw it noted somewhere that using javascript to make the request is a bit more common or otherwise a hidden iframe. That's going to depend though.  To make this happen using the "implicit" workflow, as I've used, the token is exposed to the browser (user agent). In my own code I've set [httponly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) on the cookie, but that's my own implementation choice. So yes, I guess the limit is whether the Identity provider set HttpOnly, that would stop XHR working, because it MUST have the client session cookies for the identity provider to work.

Comment: Oh so you're using the implicit workflow with third party cookies? I gotcha. Then yeah I guess you just call `authorize` from Javascript or in a hidden iframe, but either way that'll, give you cookie back - and then you can immediately start making XHR calls to the IDP (even if it is httponly, which I have to imagine it would be). I've only ever used explicit workflow because of third-party cookie issues. Well glad it seems to have worked out for you.

Comment: @EmperorEto Both work, it doesn't have to be implicit workflow. But the feature here that I'm near certain is wrong in many blogs is this: refresh tokes are for when you want to give an app long-term access to a resource without the user present. something like letting a little third party "reminder" app read your calendar, even if you aren't looking at it. In that case you want the reminder app to be able to refresh it's token. In the case of single sign on, that's the opposite of what you want. You want the user to bounce off the identity provider themselves to prove they are still there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for are [refresh tokens](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/).

I can verify this basic procedure works for Azure AD (which I use it for), but I imagine the process is similar for other IDPs. Note this is for an explicit workflow (using the JWT in the `Authorization` header) rather than cookie-based.

When you know your JWT has expired, call the `oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint to get a new one, rather than `/authorize`. In the form specify:

- `grant_type` = `refresh_token`
- `refresh_token` = the expired JWT

You will likely need to also include the same parameters used to get the original token, such as `redirect_uri`, `scope`, `nonce`, etc. Different providers might have different requirements here. (For example, AAD requires users to have granted the "offline access" permission to the application in order to use refresh tokens at all).

This is going to be a `POST` with a return value rather than a simple HTTP redirect, and if it succeeds the `refresh_token` member of the response will be populated with your new JWT, which you can in turn use to get another refresh token when that one expires, etc.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) goes into much more detail about how to do this with AAD. I know you're using Google and others but again assuming everyone is following the standard the logic flow should be very similar.

Comment: I don't think this can be the missing point in my knowledge: 1) I'm not getting a refresh token back from authorise unless I chose offline mode [which feels incorrect for me to do] 2) I see no way to use the refresh token when the same user logs in from a new device. As a user I've never had to grant permission a second time just because I switched devices. Thank you for the Microsoft link, as usual Microsoft documentation is better written.

Comment: @PhilipCouling ah ok. I thought the quick expiration of the initial token was your underlying issue but it sounds like the IDP asking the user to confirm permissions at every login (on every device) is your bigger concern. In that case I think Gary Archer's answer is more relevant, especially the first part. This seems to be entirely IDP-specific; AAD for example never re-asks for permission unless I change the declared scopes, and it sounds like his answer has some specific ideas to try with Auth0.

Comment: About the refresh token, you're right that you have to choose offline mode (as I said AAD requires that too). I don't think it's incorrect; it's really a misnomer. It just means that you want a token that you can use for extended periods of time without re-authenticating. You could save this in localstorage or as a persistent cookie and then the user wouldn't have to reauthenticate repeatedly from the same device for as long as they're "logged in". But no this wouldn't help across devices unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah at this time I'm in two minds about whether it's a misnomer or whether its use is so frequently abused that people don't know it's wrong (AKA a very popular myth). AFAIK the refresh token persists long (months) after it's creation and it's intended purpose was intended to be for integrations that need access to the resource without the user present. But that idea is heavily dependent on there being alternatives that don't behave this way.

Comment: Thanks again for linking the google documentation. That actually got me the missing piece. As I'm not doing anything with Microsft I handn't thought of using theirs.  They have MUST better documentation of the workflows than others including what happens when sessions *expire*!

Answer (score 1):

**CONSENT PROMPTS**

The consent prompt behaviour should be a property of the identity and access management system. When a third-party app is using the user's personal assets, it should be activated, to inform the user. When a first-party app is being used, where data is not owned by the user, it is usually deactivated.

Auth0 behaviour is documented in the [Auth0 consent docs](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/applications/confidential-and-public-applications/user-consent-and-third-party-applications) and includes a `Skip Consent` option. I believe there is an Auth0 specific rule that this does not work for `localhost` - to get round this, see the note on adding an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Meanwhile, a user might use Google sign-in for many scenarios, to access both both third-party and first-party apps. In such scenarios the IDP may choose to always present a prompt to inform the user that their identity, typically a value such as a UUID, will be returned to the app.

**ID TOKENS AND WEB SESSIONS**

An ID token represents proof of the authentication event, It can be used to bootstrap a session within your web application. This is typically done by issuing an application level session cookie after login, with a lifetime you decide, which doesn't have to be based on the ID token expiry.

This type of cookie option is typically used for static browser based apps that write no security code. When the cookie expiry time expires, the browser is abruptly redirected to sign the user in again.

It is preferred these days to use `response_type=code` by the way, to avoid returning tokens in browser responses. This prevents revealing information to server logs or the browser history.

**INTERACTIVE BROWSER BASED APPS**

If instead you want an SPA that makes Ajax requests to backend APIs, then using a more complete OAuth solution is preferred, using access and refresh tokens. These can also be wrapped in secure cookies.

Your app then manages login by redirecting to an authorization server, eg Auth0, which can then authenticate the user in many possible ways, eg passwords, Google, WebAuthn and so on.

After login you then configure the authorization server to issue access tokens modelled to protect your data, along with refresh tokens so that you can keep access tokens short lived.

In this type of setup, token permissions (scopes and claims) are authorized by backend APIs. The session time is determined by AIs and thus is that of the refresh token. The frontend also has finer control over behaviour such as redirects.

**SUMMARY**

So it sounds like next steps are to write some code in the CDN in front of your static content, depending on which model you prefer. The [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) has further best practice recommendations.

Comment: I updated my answer then. There are a couple of possible expiry models.